# rest api throwing max tries exceeded error

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am trying to connect to a website via RESTful API. A token has to be generated to access the methods. And its working file since i can access data through all the methods but i am stuck at this one.

My code So far:

```
class FlipkartAPI:
    def __init__(self, token, sandbox=False):
        self.token = token
        self.session = self.get_session()
        self.sandbox = sandbox

    def get_session(self):
        session = requests.Session()
        session.headers.update({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.token,
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
    })
    return session


def returns(self, source, modified_after=None, created_after = None):
    if self.sandbox == False:
        url = "http://api.flipkart.net/returns"
    else:
        url = "http://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/returns"
    payload = {'source':source,
               'modifiedAfter':modified_after,
               'createdAfter': created_after}
    return self.session.get(url, params = payload)
```

test.py:

```
class ListOrders:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app_id = 'app_id'
        self.app_secret = 'app_secret'
        auth = Authentication(self.app_id, self.app_secret, sandbox=False)
        get_token = auth.get_access_token()
        token_str = get_token.json()
        token = token_str['access_token']

        self.flipkart = FlipkartAPI(token, sandbox=False)

    def ret(self):
        r = self.flipkart.returns('customer_return', modified_after='2015-09-01', created_after='2015-09-01')
        print r.url
        print r.status_code
```

The problem is that i am getting max tries exceeded error every time i call `ret` method. And It doesn't even print url and the status_code for the request. [Link to Documentation](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIRef.html#get-returns). What i am i doing wrong? I can access other method so there is no problem with the token generation.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 131, in <module>
    r = x.ret()
  File "test.py", line 123, in ret
    r = self.flipkart.returns('customer_return')
  File "/home/manish/Desktop/Flipkart_Api_Main/api.py", line 77, in returns
    return self.session.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.flipkart.net', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /returns (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

EDIT: POSTMAN APP DATA
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bx5p.png)

Comment: The site responded to `ping` but returns nothing by using `curl`.....?

Comment: Yes. I am using the other methods described in Documentation link and they are working fine.

Comment: See if you can reproduce it using CURL or Postman

Comment: @remus i added images with postman data.

Comment: Looks to me like either you're building the request wrong then, or their API is busted.

Comment: @remus I am using this method like I am using other `GET` methods from same API. I  also have added reference to the API documentation.

Comment: Hence my latter suggestion ;)

Comment: Have you tried contacting them for support?

Comment: Yes I have, But No response .. That's why I am trying to figure it out on my own. I want to be sure that there is no error from my side.

Comment: It really doesn't look like it - maybe try hounding them on Twitter?